# Why is BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returning null with camerax?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to create a simple android app with native c++. the goal here is to use the camera to capture an image, send it to c++ through JNI, process it, and output the image on ImageView.

here's my code :

CameraActivity.java

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'ar' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ar");
    }

    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider;
    CameraSelector cameraSelector;

    ImageView imageView;

    private void startImageAnalysis() {
        // Create an ImageAnalysis use case
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        // Create a HandlerThread to handle the image analysis on a separate thread
        HandlerThread analyzerThread = new HandlerThread("ImageAnalyzer");
        analyzerThread.start();
        Handler analyzerHandler = new Handler(analyzerThread.getLooper());

        // Create an Executor using the Handler from the HandlerThread
        Executor analyzerExecutor = new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
                analyzerHandler.post(runnable);
            }
        };

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(analyzerExecutor, image -> {
            // Get the image buffer as a ByteBuffer
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();

            // Convert the ByteBuffer to a byte[] array
            byte[] imageData = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(imageData);

            Log.d("MyApp", "Processing image");

            // Call the JNI wrapper function with the buffer and its dimensions
            processImageWrapper(imageData, width, height);

            // Close the image to release the resources
            image.close();
        });

        // Bind the ImageAnalysis use case to the camera
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis);
    }

    private void stopImageAnalysis() {
        // TODO: Unbind the ImageAnalysis use case from the camera
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        com.example.ar.databinding.ActivityCameraBinding binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        // Initialize the camera provider future
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        // Wait for the camera provider to be available
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                // Get the camera provider
                cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                // Bind the camera to the preview
                bindCamera(cameraProvider);

            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("CameraXActivity", "Error binding camera", e);
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));



    }

    private void bindCamera(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        // Create an image capture use case and set it up
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build();

        // Select the back camera as the default
        cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();


        startImageAnalysis();

    }

    // Declare the native function
    public native byte[] processImage(byte[] imageData, int width, int height);

    // Define the JNI wrapper function
    private void processImageWrapper(byte[] imageData, int width, int height) {
        // Call the native function with the buffer and its dimensions and receive the processed image
        byte[] processedImageData = processImage(imageData, width, height);

        // Create a BitmapFactory.Options object to specify the image format
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // Set the format to ARGB_8888

        // Convert the processed image byte array to a Bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(processedImageData, 0, processedImageData.length, options);


        // Set the Bitmap to the ImageView to render it on the screen
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

Here is the code of the c++ function, it returns the same image without processing :

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_example_ar_CameraActivity_processImage(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */, jbyteArray image_data, jint width, jint height) {
    // Get a pointer to the input image data
    jbyte* input_image_data = env->GetByteArrayElements(image_data, NULL);

    // Check if the input image data is null
    if (input_image_data == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create a new byte array to hold the output image data
    jbyteArray output_image_data = env->NewByteArray(width * height * 4);

    // Check if the output image data is null
    if (output_image_data == NULL) {
        // Release the input image data
        env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(image_data, input_image_data, JNI_ABORT);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Copy the input image data to the output image data
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(output_image_data, 0, width * height * 4, input_image_data);

    // Release the input image data
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(image_data, input_image_data, JNI_ABORT);

    // Return the output image data
    return output_image_data;
}
```

When debugging, I figured out that this line in returning null :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(processedImageData, 0, processedImageData.length, options);
```

`processedImageData` is not null.

Can anyone help ?

I tried debugging with android studio's debug tool, I tried running :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
```

and it returns null also.

`imageData` is the image captured by the camera before being sent to c++.

imageData and processedImageData have the same value (since the procee  function doesn't do anything for now). the value looks like something like this :

[10, 7, 5, 7, 11, 7, 8, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 9, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 5, 4, 7, 8, 5, 5, 8, 4, 6, 7, 9, 4, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 9, 7, 2, 5, 3, 7, 5, 4, 9, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 8, 7, 9, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 4, 11, 0, 6, 6, 5, 9, 8, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6, 10, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 9, 2, 6, 6, 5, 3, 5, 9, 5, 5, 9, 4, 9, +307,100 more]

Comment: The byte array should contain a valid jpg or png file. You did not tell what was in the array. If content invalid null is returned

Comment: Also a null is returned when the intended bitmap would become to big for memory of device.

Comment: You just can find out by saving the content of the byte array to file and inspect the file with a number of viewers.

Comment: Hello @blackapps

As you can see, the byte array contains the captured image of the camera. Basically, I'm trying to preview the captured image on the screen

Comment: `As you can see, the byte array contains the captured image of the camera.` My god... you tell nothing more and you are not telling if it is a jpg or png or other type. READ PLEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `ImageProxy` from `ImageAnalysis` is YUV format, which means it contains 3 planes, each for the Y, U and V component. You are using the first plane and treated it as JPEG format, which is why it doesn't work.

In order to get a `Bitmap` from the YUV `ImageProxy`, simply call [ImageProxy.toBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy#toBitmap()) if you are on the latest version.